# How to declare a generic variable as a function of time in Maplesoft so that chainrule can be applied?

Tags: maple

I hope someone could give me some help on using Maple for symbolic computation.

Below is my code to declare a generic variable `eta` as a function of time:
[image]

I notice that when I differentiate `eta` with respect to time , 0 is returned. However, what I would like to have is eta_dot. Ultimately I would like to take the time derivative of column matrix at the very bottom in the screenshot above. How should I acheive this?

Comment: Nobody wants to have to re-type your code, from a hazy image. You should include a plaintext version of code that you expect people here to be able to execute (such as your Vector definition...) Or include a URL for a download of the .mw worksheet. Or use a forum that allows attachments, such as www.mapleprimes.com the Maplesoft user-forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line,

```
eta := t -> eta
```

is meaningless, and should be removed (to avoid it confusing things).

Elsewhere, if you intended `eta` to represent an (unspecified/placeholder) expression in `t` you should be using `eta(t)` instead.

For example,

```
restart;
# examples with unspecified functions of t

eta(t);

          eta(t)

diff(eta(t), t);

          d        
         --- eta(t)
          dt       

expr1 := sin(eta(t));

          expr1 := sin(eta(t))

diff(expr1, t);

       / d        \            
       |--- eta(t)| cos(eta(t))
       \ dt       /            

expr2 := sin(eta(t)) * cos(beta(t));

   expr2 := sin(eta(t)) cos(beta(t))

diff(expr2, t);

   / d        \                         
   |--- eta(t)| cos(eta(t)) cos(beta(t))
   \ dt       /                         

                   / d         \             
     - sin(eta(t)) |--- beta(t)| sin(beta(t))
                   \ dt        /
```

You didn't explain what that Vector represents, so that part of you question is unclear. I will mention that I see what look like several missing multiplication signs (explicit *, or implicit space to denote that) in your 2D Math image. I suggest you be very careful with that, and if it's a recurring source of syntax mistakes for you, that you consider switching to 1D plaintext "Maple Notation" for input.